# When deploying a single liferay ext I get 404 resource not found

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I created a simple liferay ext plugin and in the portal-ext.properties, I override a property of liferay. I start the server add the ext project and deploy. When I access localhost:8080, I get

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading jar:file:/C:/lpt/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-

INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
09:07:50,045 ERROR [ContextLoader:225] Context initialization failed
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:314)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:168)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(URL.java:1144)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:572)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:977)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:966)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:146)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1382)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locateFromClasspath(ConfigurationUtils.java:576)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:558)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:237)
    at com.germinus.easyconf.AggregatedProperties.addFileProperties(AggregatedProperties.java:164)
    at com.germinus.easyconf.AggregatedProperties.addPropertiesSource(AggregatedProperties.java:140)
```

(I couldnt dump the entire console)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot posting the code and the properties file. So far we know *that* you changed *something*, and that it results in an error. What level of help do you expect from this amount of information?

Comment: in the portal-ext.properties I added users.delete=false. As for the code I didnt write any. I simply created a new liferay plugin, selected ext.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror). You should try to add the whole stacktrace, or at least tell us how much lines you have dropped. I would guess that you have either a to small stack size (try setting the VM option `-Xss`) or that you dropped the loop from your stacktrace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the solution to the error, but a work around to the problem was to copy all the original folders to a new folder and start the process of liferay build services and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Liferay development!

You do not need an EXT plugin to change portal-ext.properties.  Just put the file in the ${LIFERAY_HOME} directory (normally the parent directory of your app server) and Liferay will process it at restart.

And you should really try to avoid EXT plugins unless absolutely necessary.  First they are deprecated by Liferay, but more importantly is that they cannot be undeployed or easily updated.  So undoing an EXT deployment usually ends badly.